# How can I fix image pushing down text?

Tags: html, css

```css
.courseinfo{
margin:0px;
text-align:center;
}
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

    .jumbotron {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-image: url(image.jpg);
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }

    .navigation {
      background-color: #330;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    }

    .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
    }

    .navigation a:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .navigation a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    .intro {
      background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

    .secondbg {
      background-image: url("circuit.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;

      align-items: top;

    } 

    .barofcolour {

      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      padding: 1%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }

    .coursep {
      width:40%;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      margin-left: 1%
    }

    .whatwelearn{
      text-align: left;
      width:50%;
      font-size: 40px;
      margin:1%;
    }

    .listoflearn {
      width:40%;
      font-size: 28px;
      margin:1%;
    }

    .backoftable {
      background-color: burlywood;
      width:40%;
      margin-left: 1%;
      padding-top: 0.05%;
      padding-bottom: 0.05%;
      border-left: 1%;
    }

    .learningpic{
      align-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    Home - Hasan's Website
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
  </div>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>

    </div>


  </div>

<div class="secondbg">
  <div class = "barofcolour">
      <div class="courseinfo">
        <h2>About This Course
        </h2>
      </div>

  </div>
```

How can I put the text on the right side of the burlywood box, and at the same level as the text? Whenever I place the Psychology image, the list and what we learn title gets pushed down! How can I fix this? I want the text and the image at the same altitude, but the image to the right of the box. This assignment is for school. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: @faizan-khan  ummm.... you took the parts that are related to the question out of the code snippet.... (?)

Comment: @elbrant which parts?

Comment: @elbrant HTML and CSS both are available

Comment: @faizan-khan all of the HTML, starting from `<div class="coursep">` all the way to `</html>`

Comment: @john-bob Could you tell us how big the image is (or upload it)? That would make it much easier to resolve your issue. (thx)

Comment: @elbrant sure. The image is 303 × 303 and it is the colourful brain of this website. https://oupeltglobalblog.com/2018/03/27/psychology-language-learning/

Comment: hello bob is your html missing some classes?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

- I nested your `.listoflearn` HTML inside your `.whatwelearn` class,
  so they would group together.
- I added floats to the three elements in the `.backoftable` class. The
  image, `float:left;`; the text, `float:right;`.
- I also deleted the `border-left:1%;` from the `.backoftable` class.
- and, I tweaked the width percentages somewhat. Not sure if that will affect your assignment, but ... I felt like it was neccessary given the font size.

```css
.courseinfo{
    margin:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

h1 {
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

.secondbg {
      background-image: url("circuit.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: top;
    }

.barofcolour {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      padding: 1%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }

.coursep {
      width:40%;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      margin-left: 1%
    }

.backoftable {
    background-color: burlywood;
    width:50%;
    height:45%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 0.05%;
    padding-bottom: 0.05%;
}

.learningpic{
    float:left;
    align-content: center;
    }

.whatwelearn{
    float:right;
    text-align: left;
    width:60%;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin:1%;
    }

.listoflearn {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin:1%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="secondbg">
  <div class = "barofcolour">
      <div class="courseinfo">
        <h2>About This Course</h2>
      </div>
  </div>

   <div class="coursep">
    <p>This course examines computer systems and control of external devices. Students will develop
      knowledge and skills in electronics, interfacing, programming, and networks, will build systems that
      use computer programs and interfaces to control and respond to external devices. Students will
      develop an awareness of related environmental and societal issues, and will learn about college and
      university programs leading to careers in computer technology.</p>
  </div>


 <div class = "backoftable">
      <div class = "learningpic">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/oupeltglobalblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Psychology.jpg?resize=400%2C400&ssl=1" alt="Learning" width="303" height="303">
      </div>
    <div class = "whatwelearn">
      <h2>What We Learn:</h2>
    <div class = "listoflearn">
        <ul>
            <li>Web Development</li>
            <li>Basic Electronics</li>
            <li>Programming</li>
            <li>Digital Electronics</li>
            <li>Interfacing</li>
            <li>Technology Environment Careers Safety Society</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Note: The image came from the Oxford University Press website.](https://oupeltglobalblog.com/2018/03/27/psychology-language-learning/)

p.s. Please view this at "full size" to see it properly.

Comment: You were close, but I really want the brain on the RIGHT side. Also, I really need the both bars of colour to be equal sizes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nevermind.  I fixed it. Thank you so much! You are truly a legend!